# No option for device deployment in top-left menu on Xcode

Tags: xcode, deployment, xcodebuild

after I opened a downloaded project on Xcode, the option allowing me to deploy my applications on my devices has disappered:

Before I had:

Device
Simulator on the top of the list, now I have this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W11q6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a **Base SDK** set for your Simulator and Target.

[image]

Right-Click on these and choose `Get Info`, then choose `Build` and make sure that **Base SDK** is set to **Latest** *(Xcode 3.2.5+)*, If your Xcode is older than 3.2.5, choose any SDK.

*Also note, that if you have Xcode 3.2.5, then you need to exit out of Xcode, and reopen the project.*

Comment: Ok I have latest sdk but The option "Device" isn't ther yet

Comment: Yes, you have to close Xcode out, then reopen. Its a very annoying step, but I assure you it will work upon relaunching Xcode. ;-)